# Java Function in 1.7 (convert lambda expressions)

Tags: java, java-7

I am working on an old java application that uses Java 1.7. I would like to make use of the `java.util.function.Function` interface. However, this is only supported in Java 1.8+.

So I would like to write my own implementation in Java 1.7.

```
import java.util.Objects;

public interface Function<T, R> {
    
    R apply(T t);
    
    default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(before);
        return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v)); // lambda expression
    }
    
    default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t)); // lambda expression
    }
    
    static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return t -> t; // lambda expression
    }
}
```

The above gives me compile errors on the lambda expressions.

**Question**

How do I write the above lambda expressions in Java 1.7?

Comment: Do not longer use java7 ist is outdated since many years

Comment: Hi Jens, I would like to upgrade to java 1.8+, but this is a legacy application that was written many years ago.

Comment: I don't see how you want to actually create this interface since even the interface `default` feature is provided only with Java 8.

Comment: I seriously advise to *not* do this. This will lead to problems if a decision got made to use the newer Java API's. This will lead to a maintenance hazard in the future. It is better to stick with the tools you have, do not create a new one yourself when these are already "available in store". Better to vouch for a java JRE/SDK update.

Comment: "this is a legacy application that was written many years ago" - how does it stop you from moving to newer Java version? Of course it's legacy application if it's writen in Java 7 - noone sane would write anything new in so old Java version.

Comment: If this is a legacy app, I would recommend NOT trying to retrofit lambda and similar advanced stuff to it.  Instead, spend your effort in either porting the app to Java 8 (sooner) or rewriting it.

Comment: @Amongalen you cannot simply upgrade Java to newer versions. It really depends of the dependencies, time to move over all current developers contributing to the software and time to update the JRE's on the target platforms. Many managers aren't really maintenance-oriented.

Comment: @KarelG Upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8 should be almost effortless and painless. Things are a bit different going to Java 9 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't actually create an interface with default methods, I think your best chance are static methods.

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);

    public static <T, V, R> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before, Function<? super T, ? super R> after) {
        return new CombiningFunction<T, V, R>(before, after);
    }
    
    public static <T, R, V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super T, ? super R> before, Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        return new CombiningFunction<T, V, R>(before, after);
    }
    
    static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return new Function<T, T> {
            T apply(T t) { return t; }
        }
    }
}

class CombiningFunction<T, V, R> implements Function<T, R> {
    Function<T, V> first;
    Function<V, R> second;

    public R apply(T t) {
        V intermediate = first.apply(t);
        return second.apply(intermediate);
    }
}
```

But like KarelG mentions in the comments, it's really not advisable to do this; not to mention that this isn't nearly as elegant as in Java 8; after all, functional interfaces are pretty much geared towards lambdas, and if you don't have them, all usage will be as awkward as the implementation above.

Comment: `Class 'CombiningFunction' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'apply(T)' in 'Function'`

Comment: @Richard I meant to declare it as `Function<T, R>` obviously. Corrected in edit.

Comment: On `return new CombiningFunction<T, V, R>(before, after);`, it get's the following compile error:  `Expected 0 arguments but found 2`

Comment: @Richard Yeah I left out the constructor for that class for brevity's sake.

Comment: If I add a constructor, it makes no difference, I still get the compile errors:  `CombiningFunction(Function<T, V> first, Function<V, R> second) {`

Comment: Do you know what the constructor should be?  I try the following with no success: `public <V, T, R> CombiningFunction(Function<? super V,? extends T> before, Function<? super T,? super R> after) {
    }`.

Comment: You cannot put static methods in interfaces before Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *IntellijIdea* to change it automatically, There is a result of **IntellijIdea**:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public interface Function<T, R> {

    R apply(T t);

    default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(before);
        return new Function<V, R>() {
            @Override
            public R apply(V v) {
                return Function.this.apply(before.apply(v));
            }
        }; // lambda expression
    }

    default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        Function<T, V> tvFunction = new Function<T, V>() {
            @Override
            public V apply(T t) {
                return after.apply(Function.this.apply(t));
            }
        };
        return tvFunction; // lambda expression
    }

    static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return new Function<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public T apply(T t) {
                return t;
            }
        }; // lambda expression
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  In intelliJ, where is the command to convert it?

Comment: Extension methods are not supported at language level '7'.

Comment: This is no command! Just move cursor at the Lambda Expression, an orange Icon will be displayed at left of the line, click on them, it suggest some improvement, one of them is "Lambda change to class definition".

Comment: You can also change Extension methods by accepting Intellij suggest.